# jQuery datetimepicker don't allow to select past time

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

Hi I have a simple jQuery datetimepicker

```
$('#activity_date').datetimepicker({
    format      :'Y/m/d',
    timepicker  : false,
    minDate     : 0
});

$('#activity_start_time').datetimepicker({
    format      :'H:i',
    datepicker  : false
});
```

I can limit the start date but how can I make the finish time not earlier than the start time?

Thanks

Comment: someone has already wrote a function here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17564868/1936024

Comment: @KishorPawar Make sure you close/flag this question as a duplicate then.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I tried, but the questions has no accepted answer.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for your response. I will check it out and mark this as duplicate thanks :)

Comment: @KishorPawarit it is a datetimepicker and not a timepicker so there was an error: TypeError: $(...).timepicker is not a function
$('#activity_start_time').timepicker({

But I will try to use timepicker instead of datetimepicker

Answer (score 0):

please  only remove

```
minDate:0
```

from Datepicker

use like

```
$('#activity_date').datetimepicker({
    format      :'Y/m/d',
    timepicker  : false,
});
```